# Sapiência, Sabedoria ou Ciência?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, sinônimos

Preciso traduzir em português um texto que fala da Sofia, a Sabedoria Divina. Em italiano há muitas distinções que penso existirem em português também, mas não estou certo e portanto: qual é a distinção entre Sabedoria, Sapiência e Ciência (se existe). Há também outras palavras relacionadas que podem ser utilizadas?

Comment: Tu poderias dar o exemplo da frase em que a palavra seria usada, deixando um espaço em branco?  Ficaria mais fácil para nós dizer qual das três palavras melhor transmite o que tu queres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As três palavras são substantivos relacionadas ao conhecimento. A diferença está na conotação.

1. **Sapiência**, além de ser uma linguagem mais formal, tem sentido de conhecimento absoluto ou divino.

   > A sapiência de Deus é inquestionável.
2. A **sabedoria** tem tom de conhecimento informal, genérico ou
   abrangente.

   > A sabedoria dos idosos deve ser compartilhada com os jovens.
3. A **ciência** pode se referir a:

   - Um ramo de conhecimento como campo de estudo.

     > A matemática é uma ciência exata.
   - Como o conhecimento de fatos, estar consciente e a par de situações.

     > 1) Eu tenho ciência de que meus atos tem consequências. 
     >   2) Perguntei a ela o que havia ocorrido, mas na verdade eu já tinha ciência de todos os acontecimentos.